# How can I have an optional Sbt setting?

Tags: scala, reflection, sbt, sbteclipse

There is a project shared with multiple participants. Some participants installed a global sbteclipse at `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt`, while other participants didn't.

I want to put some sbt settings in the project's `build.sbt`, like:

```
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.Unmanaged + EclipseCreateSrc.Managed + EclipseCreateSrc.Source
```

I wish to apply these settings only for those participants who have installed a global sbteclipse, and do not affect others.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to use some complex settings like:

```
try {
  Class.forName("com.typesafe.sbteclipse.plugin.EclipsePlugin$EclipseKeys").getMethod("createSrc").invoke(null).asInstanceOf[SettingKey[_]] := ...
catch {
  case e: Exception => Seq.empty : SettingsDefinition
}
```

I am still looking for a better solution.